# Validation loss is keep decreasing while training loss starts to increase after 3 epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, lstm

I am training a LSTM model with a trained Word2Vec and after 3 epochs i started to observe that my training loss starts to increase while validation loss still keeps decreasing. And it is the same case for the accuracy. Training accuracy starts to decrease and validation accuracy keeps increasing. Here are the figures for the comparison and also my model parameters.

My learning rate is default set which is 0.001 and i cannot decide if i should keep training or cut the training when training loss starts to increase.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

```
model = Sequential()
#model.add(Embedding(maximum_words_number, e_dim, input_length=X.shape[1]))
model.add(Embedding(58137, 100, weights = [embeddings] ,input_length=X_train.shape[1],trainable = False)) # -> This adds Word2Vec encodings
model.add(LSTM(10,return_sequences= True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(10,return_sequences= False, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
#opt = SGD(lr=0.05)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer="Nadam", metrics=['accuracy'])
epochs = 4
batch_size = 100
model_outcome = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,validation_split=0.2,callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=1, min_delta=0.0001)])
```

```
Train on 3931 samples, validate on 983 samples
Epoch 1/4
3931/3931 [==============================] - ETA: 2:56:26 - loss: 0.6879 - accuracy: 0.580 - ETA: 2:46:13 - loss: 0.6891 - accuracy: 0.530 - ETA: 2:34:51 - loss: 0.6845 - accuracy: 0.556 - ETA: 2:26:49 - loss: 0.6820 - accuracy: 0.570 - ETA: 2:21:09 - loss: 0.6846 - accuracy: 0.550 - ETA: 2:15:42 - loss: 0.6823 - accuracy: 0.573 - ETA: 2:10:58 - loss: 0.6822 - accuracy: 0.565 - ETA: 2:06:02 - loss: 0.6854 - accuracy: 0.547 - ETA: 2:01:00 - loss: 0.6850 - accuracy: 0.558 - ETA: 1:56:26 - loss: 0.6833 - accuracy: 0.563 - ETA: 1:53:31 - loss: 0.6820 - accuracy: 0.573 - ETA: 1:50:38 - loss: 0.6817 - accuracy: 0.574 - ETA: 1:47:40 - loss: 0.6815 - accuracy: 0.573 - ETA: 1:44:31 - loss: 0.6802 - accuracy: 0.582 - ETA: 1:41:28 - loss: 0.6782 - accuracy: 0.585 - ETA: 1:38:09 - loss: 0.6779 - accuracy: 0.581 - ETA: 1:34:40 - loss: 0.6769 - accuracy: 0.580 - ETA: 1:30:53 - loss: 0.6768 - accuracy: 0.580 - ETA: 1:26:56 - loss: 0.6754 - accuracy: 0.584 - ETA: 1:22:56 - loss: 0.6739 - accuracy: 0.587 - ETA: 1:18:52 - loss: 0.6723 - accuracy: 0.590 - ETA: 1:14:51 - loss: 0.6703 - accuracy: 0.592 - ETA: 1:10:43 - loss: 0.6680 - accuracy: 0.597 - ETA: 1:06:38 - loss: 0.6648 - accuracy: 0.606 - ETA: 1:02:26 - loss: 0.6616 - accuracy: 0.611 - ETA: 58:10 - loss: 0.6594 - accuracy: 0.6142  - ETA: 53:56 - loss: 0.6580 - accuracy: 0.615 - ETA: 49:37 - loss: 0.6572 - accuracy: 0.616 - ETA: 45:18 - loss: 0.6553 - accuracy: 0.618 - ETA: 40:57 - loss: 0.6545 - accuracy: 0.619 - ETA: 36:36 - loss: 0.6527 - accuracy: 0.622 - ETA: 32:15 - loss: 0.6493 - accuracy: 0.626 - ETA: 27:52 - loss: 0.6478 - accuracy: 0.628 - ETA: 23:29 - loss: 0.6455 - accuracy: 0.630 - ETA: 19:06 - loss: 0.6424 - accuracy: 0.634 - ETA: 14:41 - loss: 0.6396 - accuracy: 0.637 - ETA: 10:15 - loss: 0.6378 - accuracy: 0.640 - ETA: 5:49 - loss: 0.6354 - accuracy: 0.643 - ETA: 1:22 - loss: 0.6335 - accuracy: 0.64 - 10937s 3s/step - loss: 0.6331 - accuracy: 0.6459 - val_loss: 0.5066 - val_accuracy: 0.7792
Epoch 2/4
3931/3931 [==============================] - ETA: 3:03:31 - loss: 0.6418 - accuracy: 0.660 - ETA: 2:57:39 - loss: 0.5754 - accuracy: 0.710 - ETA: 2:50:26 - loss: 0.5706 - accuracy: 0.716 - ETA: 2:55:55 - loss: 0.5607 - accuracy: 0.720 - ETA: 2:55:39 - loss: 0.5552 - accuracy: 0.718 - ETA: 2:55:12 - loss: 0.5473 - accuracy: 0.731 - ETA: 2:52:50 - loss: 0.5440 - accuracy: 0.737 - ETA: 2:49:19 - loss: 0.5391 - accuracy: 0.740 - ETA: 2:45:24 - loss: 0.5380 - accuracy: 0.740 - ETA: 2:41:00 - loss: 0.5361 - accuracy: 0.740 - ETA: 2:36:48 - loss: 0.5414 - accuracy: 0.734 - ETA: 2:32:57 - loss: 0.5357 - accuracy: 0.738 - ETA: 2:28:34 - loss: 0.5292 - accuracy: 0.743 - ETA: 2:24:22 - loss: 0.5240 - accuracy: 0.747 - ETA: 2:19:52 - loss: 0.5230 - accuracy: 0.750 - ETA: 2:14:57 - loss: 0.5157 - accuracy: 0.757 - ETA: 2:09:42 - loss: 0.5118 - accuracy: 0.761 - ETA: 2:04:24 - loss: 0.5154 - accuracy: 0.758 - ETA: 1:59:06 - loss: 0.5126 - accuracy: 0.760 - ETA: 1:53:46 - loss: 0.5107 - accuracy: 0.760 - ETA: 1:48:16 - loss: 0.5062 - accuracy: 0.763 - ETA: 1:42:45 - loss: 0.5032 - accuracy: 0.766 - ETA: 1:37:09 - loss: 0.5041 - accuracy: 0.767 - ETA: 1:31:22 - loss: 0.5045 - accuracy: 0.766 - ETA: 1:25:30 - loss: 0.5072 - accuracy: 0.764 - ETA: 1:19:45 - loss: 0.5071 - accuracy: 0.764 - ETA: 1:13:57 - loss: 0.5094 - accuracy: 0.763 - ETA: 1:08:07 - loss: 0.5124 - accuracy: 0.763 - ETA: 1:02:15 - loss: 0.5103 - accuracy: 0.764 - ETA: 56:19 - loss: 0.5101 - accuracy: 0.7630  - ETA: 50:20 - loss: 0.5058 - accuracy: 0.766 - ETA: 44:19 - loss: 0.5052 - accuracy: 0.767 - ETA: 38:19 - loss: 0.5063 - accuracy: 0.766 - ETA: 32:18 - loss: 0.5037 - accuracy: 0.768 - ETA: 26:15 - loss: 0.5041 - accuracy: 0.768 - ETA: 20:11 - loss: 0.5054 - accuracy: 0.766 - ETA: 14:06 - loss: 0.5068 - accuracy: 0.765 - ETA: 8:00 - loss: 0.5024 - accuracy: 0.769 - ETA: 1:53 - loss: 0.5026 - accuracy: 0.76 - 14951s 4s/step - loss: 0.5024 - accuracy: 0.7698 - val_loss: 0.4381 - val_accuracy: 0.8006
Epoch 3/4
3931/3931 [==============================] - ETA: 4:10:44 - loss: 0.5040 - accuracy: 0.750 - ETA: 3:44:47 - loss: 0.4679 - accuracy: 0.780 - ETA: 3:34:11 - loss: 0.4734 - accuracy: 0.780 - ETA: 3:26:02 - loss: 0.4729 - accuracy: 0.785 - ETA: 3:16:47 - loss: 0.4638 - accuracy: 0.784 - ETA: 3:07:57 - loss: 0.4527 - accuracy: 0.796 - ETA: 3:01:40 - loss: 0.4502 - accuracy: 0.800 - ETA: 2:56:22 - loss: 0.4458 - accuracy: 0.803 - ETA: 2:50:30 - loss: 0.4472 - accuracy: 0.801 - ETA: 2:43:48 - loss: 0.4488 - accuracy: 0.797 - ETA: 2:37:21 - loss: 0.4466 - accuracy: 0.802 - ETA: 2:31:07 - loss: 0.4468 - accuracy: 0.803 - ETA: 2:24:57 - loss: 0.4453 - accuracy: 0.806 - ETA: 2:20:04 - loss: 0.4439 - accuracy: 0.810 - ETA: 2:14:58 - loss: 0.4447 - accuracy: 0.811 - ETA: 2:09:36 - loss: 0.4401 - accuracy: 0.814 - ETA: 2:03:28 - loss: 0.4381 - accuracy: 0.816 - ETA: 1:57:37 - loss: 0.4413 - accuracy: 0.813 - ETA: 1:51:48 - loss: 0.4410 - accuracy: 0.814 - ETA: 1:45:59 - loss: 0.4432 - accuracy: 0.812 - ETA: 1:40:19 - loss: 0.4404 - accuracy: 0.814 - ETA: 1:34:33 - loss: 0.4363 - accuracy: 0.817 - ETA: 1:28:51 - loss: 0.4360 - accuracy: 0.817 - ETA: 1:23:12 - loss: 0.4363 - accuracy: 0.816 - ETA: 1:17:37 - loss: 0.4371 - accuracy: 0.816 - ETA: 1:12:05 - loss: 0.4403 - accuracy: 0.817 - ETA: 1:06:31 - loss: 0.4411 - accuracy: 0.816 - ETA: 1:01:01 - loss: 0.4389 - accuracy: 0.817 - ETA: 55:32 - loss: 0.4387 - accuracy: 0.8176  - ETA: 50:05 - loss: 0.4385 - accuracy: 0.817 - ETA: 44:38 - loss: 0.4381 - accuracy: 0.818 - ETA: 39:13 - loss: 0.4329 - accuracy: 0.821 - ETA: 33:48 - loss: 0.4352 - accuracy: 0.819 - ETA: 28:25 - loss: 0.4331 - accuracy: 0.821 - ETA: 23:02 - loss: 0.4344 - accuracy: 0.820 - ETA: 17:40 - loss: 0.4377 - accuracy: 0.818 - ETA: 12:19 - loss: 0.4355 - accuracy: 0.820 - ETA: 6:58 - loss: 0.4353 - accuracy: 0.820 - ETA: 1:39 - loss: 0.4378 - accuracy: 0.82 - 12997s 3s/step - loss: 0.4374 - accuracy: 0.8204 - val_loss: 0.4065 - val_accuracy: 0.8769
Epoch 4/4
3931/3931 [==============================] - ETA: 3:19:12 - loss: 0.4999 - accuracy: 0.810 - ETA: 3:13:36 - loss: 0.4518 - accuracy: 0.825 - ETA: 3:08:18 - loss: 0.4464 - accuracy: 0.826 - ETA: 3:03:24 - loss: 0.4385 - accuracy: 0.825 - ETA: 2:58:52 - loss: 0.4385 - accuracy: 0.826 - ETA: 2:53:35 - loss: 0.4339 - accuracy: 0.825 - ETA: 2:48:13 - loss: 0.4662 - accuracy: 0.811 - ETA: 2:43:02 - loss: 0.4660 - accuracy: 0.811 - ETA: 2:37:49 - loss: 0.4609 - accuracy: 0.815 - ETA: 2:32:42 - loss: 0.4638 - accuracy: 0.816 - ETA: 2:27:37 - loss: 0.4694 - accuracy: 0.813 - ETA: 2:22:25 - loss: 0.4592 - accuracy: 0.818 - ETA: 2:17:16 - loss: 0.4590 - accuracy: 0.819 - ETA: 2:12:02 - loss: 0.4574 - accuracy: 0.820 - ETA: 2:06:47 - loss: 0.4532 - accuracy: 0.822 - ETA: 2:01:35 - loss: 0.4654 - accuracy: 0.816 - ETA: 1:56:20 - loss: 0.4732 - accuracy: 0.812 - ETA: 1:51:06 - loss: 0.4764 - accuracy: 0.811 - ETA: 1:45:54 - loss: 0.4862 - accuracy: 0.805 - ETA: 1:40:41 - loss: 0.4912 - accuracy: 0.803 - ETA: 1:35:29 - loss: 0.4930 - accuracy: 0.801 - ETA: 1:30:17 - loss: 0.4986 - accuracy: 0.797 - ETA: 1:25:03 - loss: 0.5044 - accuracy: 0.793 - ETA: 1:19:50 - loss: 0.5032 - accuracy: 0.792 - ETA: 1:14:37 - loss: 0.4999 - accuracy: 0.794 - ETA: 1:09:24 - loss: 0.4958 - accuracy: 0.796 - ETA: 1:04:11 - loss: 0.4954 - accuracy: 0.795 - ETA: 58:59 - loss: 0.4943 - accuracy: 0.7971  - ETA: 53:45 - loss: 0.4943 - accuracy: 0.796 - ETA: 48:33 - loss: 0.4902 - accuracy: 0.799 - ETA: 43:20 - loss: 0.4883 - accuracy: 0.799 - ETA: 38:07 - loss: 0.4882 - accuracy: 0.799 - ETA: 32:55 - loss: 0.4874 - accuracy: 0.800 - ETA: 27:42 - loss: 0.4839 - accuracy: 0.802 - ETA: 22:29 - loss: 0.4809 - accuracy: 0.804 - ETA: 17:16 - loss: 0.4825 - accuracy: 0.803 - ETA: 12:03 - loss: 0.4821 - accuracy: 0.803 - ETA: 6:50 - loss: 0.4810 - accuracy: 0.804 - ETA: 1:37 - loss: 0.4816 - accuracy: 0.80 - 12786s 3s/step - loss: 0.4823 - accuracy: 0.8031 - val_loss: 0.3392 - val_accuracy: 0.8911
```

Comment: Could you try with a batch_size of 32?

Comment: Sure, could you explain your reasoning?

Comment: In practice  when using a larger batch there is a significant degradation in the quality of the model, as measured by its ability to generalize. But usually we try with a batch_size of 32 as a starting point. No real reasoning behind that but it just works well.

Comment: I see, thank you for your explanation. I will get try it and see if my results change.

Comment: [This post discusses the effects of batch size in greater detail](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164876/what-is-the-trade-off-between-batch-size-and-number-of-iterations-to-train-a-neu).

Comment: It is very common to find validation loss lower than the train loss in early stages of training, try training for more epochs to see if there exists a real problem.

Comment: The thing is it took about 16 hours to train this and i was thinking of same thing and increasing the epoch to 5, but as the other guy suggested i decided to go with 32 batch size and it is gonna take a lot of time. If that is not the case i will go with 5 epoch and 100 batch.

Comment: @FatihEnes I would recommend using [EarlyStopping](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping) to stop training if the loss does not decrease after a certain number of epochs instead of training for all of the epochs.

Answer (score 0):

I think your model is too small and is overfitted on the third epoch.

Comment: My model has 10k instances with 45k features. I do not think it is too small.

Comment: @FatihEnes two LSTMs with 10 units should be small. Please add `model.summary()` to your question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when i tried to increase my lstm units i got out of memory error and could not find a overcome the issue, do you have any suggestion? First thing comes to my mind to decrease the number of features but i do not want to decrease it. Also, i will add model.summary() after i run the model.

Comment: @FatihEnes you can decrease batch_size. How much memory do you have ? Your model doesn't look big

Comment: I have about 16gb ram, yes you are right about batch_size. What is your suggestion for units and number of layers for such case? I am doing a nlp classification task with two label class.